# How can I set `tex-lacheck` as default checker?

Tags: latex, flycheck

I want to use `lacheck` as default checker in `LaTeX-mode`. By default `tex-chktex` is the main checker. I am switching into `lacheck` via `M-x flycheck-select-checker tex-lacheck`.

https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Checking

> You start `lacheck` with `C-c C-c Check <RET>` and `chktex` with `C-c C-c ChkTeX <RET>`.

---

Instead is it possible to set `tex-lacheck` as default checker in `'LaTeX-mode`?

Comment: FYI: lsp-latex + texlab could also be a good, on the fly checker.

Comment: As texlab are you referring to this: https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab ?

Comment: Yes, but you can install with brew only the executable, so it is easy (```brew install texlab```).

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how can I combine lsp-latex with texlab but let me try to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook-100 ()
        (flycheck-mode 1)
        (flycheck-select-checker 'tex-lacheck)))
```

*(I add a random number to the hook, so that even if I add one more hook to the same spot, the different hooks don't end up overriding each other.  The random numbers are intentional)*